# Why my token transfer always 0 for smart contract 1155

Tags: web3js, blockchain, tokens, ether, etherscan

I have a smart contract in solidity 1155 and am new to learning this blockchain system so do pardon me for asking weird questions. Am using metamask for transactions and my testnetwork is Ropsten.
And Deployed on Ethereum.
I can see Token iD for each Txn but i cant see the amount of  tokens transfer .Kindly guide me about it
Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Ethereum ETH value attached to the transaction. This number means no ETH was transferred outside paying the transaction gas fee.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer but can you tell me meaning of the following transaction


Tokens Transferred:
From 8a333ce09470a5e0984eda94b12
Tobd179380aa0cf501e87160f6a

ERC-1155 For 15 of Token ID [1]ERC1155

Value:
0 Ether ($0.00)
Transaction Fee:
0.000041593000457523 Ether($0.00)
Gas Price:
0.000000001000000011 Ether (1.000000011 Gwei)
Gas Limit & Usage by Txn:
62,389 | 41,593 (66.67%)
Gas Fees:
Base: 0.000000011 Gwei |Max: 1.000000022 Gwei |Max Priority: 1 Gwei

Comment: If you have a different question, I suggest open a new question. It is difficult to give any meaningful answer in comments.